# Unique slugs in Wordpress by MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, slug

I want a MySQL query to find and replace keyword in wordpress database. And want to keep slugs unique. For example : If there are 3 slugs in the `wp_terms` table :-

1. `testkeyword`
2. `testkeyword-2`
3. `testslg`

now I want to replace keyword `slg` with `keyword` and run the update query as

```
update wp_terms set `slug` = replace(slug, 'slg','keyword')
```

Now the third slug which was `testslg` will become `testkeyword`, and it will not remain unique, as the first slug exists same as the third.

How can I put a number at the end of slug if it already exists in a column?
As in this example I want the third slug to be `testkeyword-3`. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

At the start get the initial count of your newly formed keyword. Suppose you are going to replace your third keyword i.e. testslg with testkeyword using following statement

```
$newkeyword = str_replace("slg","keyword","testslg");
```

Now, get the count of this newkeyword using following query

```
SELECT count(slug) FROM wp_terms WHERE slug like '%$newkeyword%';
```

Use this count in the update query

```
update wp_terms set `slug` = '$newkeyword-$above_query_count_result' WHERE row_unique_id;
```

Note: This answer is just the logic, please include all concatenation in your php code.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you answer, but in my example "testslg" is something in database, The query will only have the keyword to find (slg) and the keyword to be replaced (keyword). so I think it is not possible to use this str_replace("slg","keyword","testslg");